# VSCode: Custom YAML formatting rules

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, redhat

Is there a way to configure the formatting rules of the Red Hat YAML formatter in VSCode?
More specifically, I would like to configure the formatting to not to indent the lists like this:

```yaml
list:
  - 1
    2
    3
```

Instead, I would like this:

```yaml
list:
- 1
  2
  3
```

Alternatively, are there any other worthwhile extensions which support this? Thanks.

Comment: what are the setting options of the formatter? If not there yet create an issue at the repo of the extension

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of digging, I have found that it looks like the [Red Hat YAML formatter does not currently support this](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/172), since the underlying [`Prettier` does not support this](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9853). It looks like this feature won't make it to Prettier since it's against its philosophy.
There's a [`Prettierx`](https://github.com/brodybits/prettierx/issues/382) fork that has issue opened regarding adding this feature.